# Array destructuring inside object

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Create a simple array and destructure it inside an (empty) object:

```
const foo: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const bar: Array<number> = {...foo};
```

Shouldn't the type check fail here ? `bar` does not look like an array to me.
Editor does not complain at all and treats `bar` as an array type even though I can easily check at runtime that it's not.

**Edit**

[Reproducing it easily in the TypeScript playground.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20foo%3A%20Array%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%5D%3B%0Aconst%20bar%3A%20Array%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20%7B...foo%7D%3B)

Comment: What version of `tsc` are you using? 2.1.4 complains about type mismatch.

Comment: @Saravana spot on. Just checked from command line and I get the error. So the issue is from the editor (vscode) in this case.

Comment: Although I can reproduce it in the TypeScript playground, see edit above.

Comment: Something broke/changed between 2.1.4 and 2.2.1 I guess. After I updated to 2.2.1 I no longer get the compiler error.

Comment: I'm also having the same behavior with v2.2.1

Comment: Probably the difference is that in the older version the spread operator was not implemented yet, hence the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It it looks like a known issue because `{...foo}` destructuring is compiled into `Object.assign({}, foo)`, and `Object.assign()` is declared as

```
assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;
```

so when the second argument is an array, the result is compatible with array type.

Hopefully it will be fixed when [better typing for Object.assign is implemented](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11100#issuecomment-249314670):

> I am close to having a PR for spread types, so when those are in,
>   Object.assign will change to have the correct type:
>
> assign(target: T, source: U): { ...T, ...U }

If implemented correctly, spread types should not consider non-enumerable properties such as `length`, so your code then will give the same error as

```
const p: Array<number> = {};

// Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
// Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'.
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets have a look at the resulting [javascript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20foo%3A%20Array%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%5D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20bar%3A%20Array%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20%7B...foo%7D%3B):

```
var __assign = (this && this.__assign) || Object.assign || function(t) {
    for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
        s = arguments[i];
        for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p))
            t[p] = s[p];
    }
    return t;
};
var foo = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var bar = __assign({}, foo);
```

So you basically create an object with the same properties as original destructured array - and as typescript is [structural typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) it will consider new object compatible with Array as it was shallow copied.

On the other hand if you will do:

```
const foo1: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const bar1: Array<number> = [...foo1];
```

The result will be as expected new instance of the array.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that '[...foo1]' works, I'm trying to understand why it's not complaining in the other case. If it would create an object with the same properties I would expect to find them there. For example the resulting object has no length property, which is present on the array.

Comment: Looks like a bug rather than expected behaviour to me. `{...foo}` is obviously an array-like and not an array. I wonder if it has been already reported.

Comment: It looks to me rather to be a trade off. On one hand we have desctructuring in typescript that copies only own enumerable properties, on the other hand we have objects like Array in javascript where most of the properties and methods are inherited from prototype. So we have two choices - either remove almost all methods and props from Array definition in lib.d.ts - so typescript will know what expect to be copied, or keep it as is - but have such side effect as you observe.